# Javascript Math: Geometric Series

Tags: javascript, math, finance

I want to create a Roth IRA value calculator. The end result would accept values for annual contribution amount, interest rate, and total number of contribution years.

The calculation—a geometric series—that I need is:

```
Balance(Y) = P(1 + r)Y + c[ ((1 + r)Y + 1 - (1 + r)) / r ]
```

FWIW, I'm getting my math information here: http://www.moneychimp.com/articles/finworks/fmbasinv.htm

How would one go about writing this in Javascript? I've been reading about the math functions, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it...

Comment: Just like you did, except use `*` for multiplication in all cases and use `()` instead of `[]`

Comment: You can use `Math.pow(x,y)` for the exponents

Comment: Your function would look something like this I believe if I understand it well:

function balance(Y, P, r, c){
       P*(1 + r)*Y + c(((1 + r)*Y + 1 - (1 + r)) / r)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  [Yann Chabot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1887927/yann-chabot) said

```
P*(1 + r)*Y + c(((1 + r)*Y + 1 - (1 + r)) / r)
```

is the right answer but just as a side note, if you dont have P initialy you should set it to 1 by default.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely read up on JavaScripts [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

A few things to note...

Grouping holds the highest precedence `()`, NOT with square brakets `[]`
square brackets are for accessing object members and array literals.

There is no operator for exponents in JavaScript use `Math.pow(x, n)`

For mathematical operations, you MUST use operators `4(x + 1)` with throw an
error telling you `4` is not a function. `4 * (x + 1)` works.

The following operators are evaluated left-right `* / % + -` with `* / %`
holding equal precedence over `+ -`. So mathematical operations are going to behave similar to `pemdas`.

Another note JavaScript is a dynamic loosely typed language. All numbers are 64-bit floating points, which can yield odd results in some math equations, e.g.

```
> .1 + .2 = 0.30000000000000004
```

[Another good read](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html)

Answer (score 1):

For solving any mathematics series below algorithm can be used. Even for some cases it will not satisfy your expected answer, but it will be correct in some other way.

Steps are as below:
    1) Get the difference between the numbers as shown below:
    2) Keep making difference until it seems same(difference get 0).
    3) Put the same last number which is coming same in that sequence and by adding that difference complete the series by coming up.

```
<pre>
Examples are as below:

1       2       3       4       5       6       **7**

   1        1       1       1       1       **1**   


1       4       9       16      25      **36**      
     3      5       7       9       **11**          
        2       2       2       **2**               



1       8       27      64      125     **216**     
    7       19      37      61      **91**          
        12      18      24      **30**              
            6       6       **6**                   
                0       **0**                       


</pre>

The same above algorithm is implemented in below js code.


<pre>
//the input

var arr=[1,4,9,16];

var pa6inoArrayMelvo = function(arrr){
var nxtArr=[];
    for(i=0;i<arrr.length;i++){
        if(arrr[i+1] != undefined){
            nxtArr.push(arrr[i+1] -arrr[i]);
        }
    }
    return nxtArr;
}
var keepArray=[];

var keepAlltheArray= function(ar){
    var tempArr=[];

        keepArray.push(ar);
        if(ar.length>1){

          tempArr=pa6inoArrayMelvo(ar);       
          keepAlltheArray(tempArr);
        }else{
            generateArray(keepArray.length-1);
            console.log("ans is:"+keepArray[0]);
        }


}

var generateArray=function(idx){
    if(keepArray[idx+1]){
        var a=keepArray[idx+1];
        var b=keepArray[idx];
        var ans=a[a.length-1]+b[a.length-1];
        keepArray[idx].push(ans);
    }else{
        var ans=keepArray[idx][keepArray[idx].length-1];
        keepArray[idx].push(ans);
    }
    if(idx>0){
        generateArray(idx-1);
    }
}

keepAlltheArray(arr);

</pre>
```